# Changing Virtual environments

Tags: python, django, virtual-environment

I cant switch my virtual environments in the command prompt. i'm new to coding so bare me. i'm running it in windows and most of the documentation i've found is using linux or mac. First I create the virtual environment directory, but then when I type activate, it uses an old virtual environment that I first created. How do I switch into the new one i create? All help is appreciated.

Comment: suppose the name of your virtual environment is `venv`, how are you activating it?

Comment: i just type activate, i dont even put in a name of it. is there a way to uplate an image?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into [virtual env wrapper for Windows](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win). It's a Windows port [Virtualenvwrapper](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper), which makes managing of virtual environments in your machine easier.

Comment: when i pip list outside of the virtual env, it says I have virturalenvwrapper-win (1.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

Check which folder are you located in when you type activate, it must be the old virtualenv folder. To activate the new virtualenv change your folder to \path_to_new_virtualenv\Scripts\ and then give activate.

Moreover, while using virtualenv the best practice is to use [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html). It makes it easiar to manage different virtualenvironments.
You should keep all your virtualenvs in a separate folder and virtualenvwrapper does it for you. If you have it installed, just make a folder **Envs**  in your user home folder. Then you just need to give

```
mkvirtualenv <venv name>
```

to create a new virtualenv and

```
workon <venv name>
```

to activate the same venv, for more commands go to [virtualenvwrapper for Windows](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win)

Comment: Thanks Animesh,I'll give it a try.

I have virtualenvwrapper-win (1.2.1)  installed currently in the root system.

Comment: okay just tried it. I can activate from anywhere in the system it seems and then if i want to switch to another env, I have to use the workon command and then whatever the name is of the env. 

i've tried searching my comp for the folder where it opens the original one but no luck. yet is there a way to change the root directory for where it pulls the command from?